# CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

I'm getting the error from the [color setFill] line of this method.  Any ideas on how I can resolve it?

```
+ (UIImage *)fillImage:(UIImage*)image withColor:(UIColor *)color
{

    // begin a new image context, to draw our colored image onto
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);

    // get a reference to that context we created
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // set the fill color
    [color setFill];

    // translate/flip the graphics context (for transforming from CG* coords to UI* coords
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, image.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    // set the blend mode to overlay, and the original image
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeOverlay);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    //if(overlay) CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, img.CGImage);

    // set a mask that matches the shape of the image, then draw (overlay) a colored rectangle
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, image.CGImage);
    CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
    CGContextDrawPath(context,kCGPathFill);

    // generate a new UIImage from the graphics context we drew onto
    UIImage *coloredImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //return the color-burned image
    return coloredImg;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `image.size`?  Perhaps it is invalid and causing `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` to not create a graphics context.

Comment: Interesting.  It's {0, 0}.  Perhaps the method's that use this one at at fault? + (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name withColor:(UIColor *)color{
    // load the image
    return [UIImage fillImage:[UIImage imageNamed:name] withColor:color];
}

Comment: @robmayoff - submit your question as an answer and I'll mark it as the solution.  It turns out there were instances where my application was attempting to use the method with a nil image.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your `image.size` isn't valid, so `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` isn't creating a graphics context.  Both `image.size.width` and `image.size.height` must be positive, finite numbers.

Possibly `image` itself is `nil`.  When you send the `size` message to `nil`, you get back `CGSizeZero`.