# <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I am new to objective-c and now I faced an issue which I don't understand how to solve. I've read this topic [CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940543/cgcontextsetfillcolorwithcolor-invalid-context-0x0) but didn't find an answer.

The problem is that I get 2 errors like this one:

> CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

This is my code:

```
#import "PushButtonView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation PushButtonView

@synthesize isAddButton;
@synthesize fillColor;

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder];
    if (!self) {
    return nil;
}
[self inspectableDefaults];
return self;
}

-(void)inspectableDefaults{
    self.isAddButton = YES;
    self.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.95 green:0.6 blue:0.5 alpha:1];    
    [self.fillColor setFill];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClearRect(context, rect);
    if (self.isAddButton) {
        self.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.85 blue:0.91 alpha:1];
    } else
    self.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.95 green:0.6 blue:0.5 alpha:1];
    [self.fillColor setFill];
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rect);

//Line characteristics
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1, 1, 1, 1);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4);

// Horizontal line
    CGPoint bezierStart = {self.bounds.origin.x + (self.bounds.size.width)/5, self.bounds.size.height/2};
    CGPoint bezierEnd = {self.bounds.size.width - (self.bounds.size.width)/5, self.bounds.size.height/2};
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, bezierStart.x, bezierStart.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, bezierEnd.x, bezierEnd.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

 // Vertical line
    if (self.isAddButton) {                    
        CGPoint bezier2Start = {self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.width - (self.bounds.size.height)/5};
        CGPoint bezier2End = {self.bounds.size.width/2, (self.bounds.origin.y + self.bounds.size.height/5)};
        CGContextBeginPath(context);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, bezier2Start.x, bezier2Start.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, bezier2End.x, bezier2End.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }

   [self.fillColor setFill];
 }
 @end
```

Comment: what happens if you comment out the `-setFill` calls?

Comment: if I comment out all the setFill calls I'll get uncoloured images but I really don't need it in the inspectableDefaults method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `inspectableDefaults` method you should not call `[self.fillColor setFill]`. The `setFill` method sets the fill color for the current graphic context, and since you don't have any context there you get this error. Just remove this line and you're good.