# Why do CGContextSetFillColorWithColor and CGContextFillRects both throw "invalid context 0x0" error?

Tags: ios, swift, cgrect, uigraphicscontext

This code:

```
    let rect = CGRectMake( 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 16.0 )
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( rect.size )
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor( context, color.CGColor )
    CGContextFillRect( context, rect )

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Is throwing these errors:

```
MakeImage[60890] <Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
MakeImage[60890] <Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
```

CGRect size seems fine, which [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940543/cgcontextsetfillcolorwithcolor-invalid-context-0x0) suggest as the problem. So what else is incorrectly set, please? Thank you.

Comment: It's saying that the `context` you are giving the CoreGraphics functions is null. This would imply that there is no current context to draw onto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the current context *after* you begin the image context.

(Apparently, when you are calling this code, before you call `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()`, there is no current context. Therefore `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` returns nil.)

```
let rect = CGRectMake( 0.0, 0.0, 16.0, 16.0 )
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( rect.size )

let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor( context, color.CGColor )
CGContextFillRect( context, rect )

let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: Apols @KurtRevis, we both posted the same answer at the same time. It's nearly midnight here and I'm making stupid mistakes. Time for bed I think. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My bad, these two were simply the wrong way around:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( rect.size )
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
```