# addSubview in a textField shows CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview

Hi I tried to add an UIImageView in my textField called typeDeProbleme. All works just fine, there's no error shown, except when I try to click on the typeDeProbleme, XCode gives me this in the Target Output:

> [Unknown process name] CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
let image = UIImage(named: "arrow")
imageView.image = image
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 15)
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
typeDeProbleme.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
typeDeProbleme.rightView = imageView
typeDeProbleme.addSubview(imageView)
```

I already tried to understand from this  [CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940543/cgcontextsetfillcolorwithcolor-invalid-context-0x0) but i can't because it's in Objective-C. Therefore, I just want to know, did I missed something here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this i think this will help you...

```
    let rightView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 15))
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 15))
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "arrow")
    rightView.addSubview(imageView)

    typeDeProbleme.rightView = rightView
    typeDeProbleme.rightViewMode = .always
```

Comment: Unfortunately not... thanks for the help though.. if you know what is the problem, could you please explain it to me?